# Firefox Click action doesn't work properly

Tags: c#, html, selenium-webdriver

I have a question to the `IWebElement.Click()` which doesn't work on specified area href.
The Webpage has about 20 items with same structure:

```
<area alt="0" shape="circle" coords="190,88,28" href="build.php?id=1">
<area alt="1" shape="circle" coords="280,89,28" href="build.php?id=2">
<area alt="2" shape="circle" coords="348,101,28" href="build.php?id=3">
<area alt="3" shape="circle" coords="132,127,28" href="build.php?id=4">
<area alt="4" shape="circle" coords="245,140,28" href="build.php?id=5">
<area alt="5" shape="circle" coords="302,147,28" href="build.php?id=6">
<area alt="6" shape="circle" coords="387,145,28" href="build.php?id=7">
<area alt="7" shape="circle" coords="72,178,28" href="build.php?id=8">
```

There are a lot more of 's.
when i access the `<area href="build.php?id=5">` the .Click action seems to be performed but without any action and causes following code to crash.
Here my C# code to access the area with id=5:

```
    String URL = "map area[href=\"build.php?id=" + id + "\"]";
    element = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) => { returnd.FindElement(By.CssSelector(URL)); });

    if (element != null)
    {       
       element.Click();
       element = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) => { return d.FindElement(By.CssSelector(button)); });
    }
```

For every area, except the one with area href$="id=5", this works. The element isn't null so the element.Click() is executed without any exception, later I get the waitexception, because the page wasn't loaded and never gets loaded by clicking ID=5.

I tried to specify much more the area's with their upper DIV, UL, LI,etc, without any solution to this problem.

I got a solution wich is:

```
    driver.Navigate().GoToURL("*/build.php?id=5");
```

but sometimes the driver.Navigate().GoToURL() opens new window or browser tab (maybe timeout of some type driver configurations?).

Note: I tried to access the element with selenium id and without any problems.

Comment: A bot of a stab in the dark, but are you sure there arent any other elements on the page with id =5? That could explain what you're seeing, another element is actually getting clicked

Comment: Actually i tried specifying the upper `<div> <ul> <li>` where `<area href="build.php?id=5">` is included, the result was that it was the only area with this specifications on the side. Also i was watching for any element with "build.php?=5" and nothing, the only links are those areas with href="build.php?id=". The other thing is, if I use the selenium ide command in firefox: click | css=area[href="build.php?id=5"] it works and opens the link. I'm stacked into this and I can't find any documentation of a known bug or something. Have you any other idea?May is there something else but Webdriver?

Comment: Is there an other technology for webautomation but webdriver and may for using with WebBrowser of .Net WPF?